# Cannot transfer survey template

Tags: 2010, list-template

Is it possible to transfer a survey template from one site collection to the other?
I saved a survey as template, uploaded to another site collection's solution library, but I cannot activate it, it is greyed out. I can activate other templates in the solution library, so it is not an authorization issue. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: It should be added to 'List Template' and not solution library.

Comment: its a site or list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add list template to 'List Template' gallery and it will available.
Go to Site setting -->  Under Web Designer Gallery --> List Template

[image]